# Angular2 How to pass a method located in other file

Tags: methods, input, routes, angular

I am quite a noob in Angular2 and typescript.

I want to pass a method from other class in a other file.

This is the file iam talking about in specific i want to pass the method deleteCondition():

```
export class ConditionBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
    conditions: Condition[] = [];
    catalog: Condition[] = [];

constructor(private _conditionService: ConditionService) { }

getConditions() {
    this._conditionService.getConditions().then(conditions => this.catalog = conditions);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getConditions();
}

onChange(conditionsIndex, catalogIndex) {

    //console.log(selectedCondition);
    //console.log(conditionsIndex);
    console.log(catalogIndex);
    this.conditions[conditionsIndex] = this.catalog[catalogIndex];
}

newCondition() {
    this.conditions.push(this.catalog[0]);
}

deleteCondition() {
    this.conditions.pop();
}
}
```

I want to pass the deleteCondition() method to an other file because in the other file this.conditions.pop() is not recognised of course.

First it was like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/92z2oe7f4w5x2b5/conditions.jpg?dl=0

Here it deletes the last created but i want to delete each condition separately like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptwq6sk6da4p21k/new.jpg?dl=0

This is the code from the SelectCondition:

```
 import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Condition} from './condition';
import {ConditionBuilderComponent} from "./conditionbuilder.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'select-condition',
    template: `
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedOperator">
                <option *ngFor="#operator of selectOperators">{{operator}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="btn-file">
                <input type="file" (click)="selectFile()" multiple />
            </span>

            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fileValue" class="form-control" readonly>

            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click)="deleteCondition()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></a>
`
})

export class SelectCondition extends Condition {
    public name: string = 'select';
    public fileValue: string;
    public selectedOperator: string = 'in';

    public selectOperators: Condition[] = [
        "in"
    ];

    selectFile() {
        $(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
            var input = $(this),
                numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
                label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
            input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
        });
    $('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {
        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
            log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

        if( input.length ) {
            input.val(log);

            console.log(input.val());
        }
    });
}

deleteCondition = () => this.deleteCondition();
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: I don't understand your question actually. In fact Angular2 handles component instances by its own so you won't be able to use the `this` keyword... What will your other file / module do with this method?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier i want to make a delete button for each line of conditions so i want to add this in the template of other conditions. So i can delete the condition where the delete key is pressed

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer why? Is it such a stupid question?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer hmm okay, is this not enough information than? I can give you a plunker where i copied all the files into: http://plnkr.co/edit/WRSbdQkla3uQlW3HLxQd?p=preview